# Java HTML in a JTextPane using # links?

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane

Is it possible to link to another link on the same page using the # link with Java html in a JTextPane.

I have tried:

```
<a href='#Bottom>

<a name='Bottom'></a>
```

and tried it:

```
<a href=\"#Bottom\">

<a name=\"Bottom\"></a>
```

Separated by a load of text in my test, but it doesn't scroll the page down to the bottom? Is it just a feature that it won't do?

TIA

Comment: I am not positive about this but I think you might have to implement your own [HyperlinkListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#addHyperlinkListener(javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener)) to do the work

Comment: Ok thanks Danny. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question simply, its not possible to do it simply as you would with HTML.